# Getting a Server-Side JsonParseException / Char code 31 on Index Creation via Nest

Tags: json, serialization, elasticsearch, nest

Good afternoon,

I am currently struggling a bit with index creation requests towards a hosted Elastic Search Service (FacetFlow), more precisely, the ES server returns a JsonParseException and returns a http 500 response and the Nest client (correctly) reports the index creation request to have failed (non valid/not acknowledged etc)

I sniffed the http traffic via fiddler and what gets sent over is the following:

```
POST https://myhostedesinstance.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io/users-dev HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic <cutforobviousreasons>
Host: myhostedesinstance.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io
Content-Length: 891

{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "number_of_shards": 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_ttl": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "dateOfBirth": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "date"
        },
        "gender": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "username": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "usernameSuggestions": {
          "type": "completion",
          "payloads": false
        },
        "id": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "createdAtUtc": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

..and  what I get back is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 21:17:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 199
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{"error":"JsonParseException[Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens\n at [Source: [B@a4fb74c; line: 1, column: 2]]","status":500}
```

I am using Nest 1.6.1 and Json.Net 7.0.1 and to 'me' that Json sent over to the server looks fine.. or am I missing something? Does anyone happen to know what might be going on?

I have not changed any serialization settings of Nest/Json.Net so I am somewhat confused why this might happen.

Comment: You may have a "tab" character after the first curly brace?...

Comment: Are you using gzip compression?

Comment: Oh my - yes. Disabled it and it works now. Thanks @MartijnLaarman !